# Testing differences between two columns, and which pairs of points are significantly different

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

I have performed paired t-test

```
data: compare2$average_1kpa and compare2$average_308kpa
t = 14.565, df = 21628, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 25.46339 33.38278
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
               29.42308
```

Does it mean there is a significant difference between the two columns.Also,how to analyse or figure out which rows are actually having significant difference ?

Comment: Yes the two samples are significantly different $p<2.2e-16$. The test does not tell you which pairs are different, since the t-test is a test of means. You could try plotting them.

Comment: I plotted the data and extracted the values which are on between 95 percent confidence interval range.Are those values the cases where there is significant difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your test indicates that the mean difference between the two groups is 29.42 and that this difference is significant, with p < 2.2e-16. It does not make sense to ask the question "which rows are significantly different?" because doing a t-test requires multiple points from each group. Comparing just one point from each group is not really meaningful*, though as user2974951 says, you could plot your data or calculate the difference between pairs of columns to get an idea of which differences are largest.

*Technically, there are methods (from Bayesian statistics) that allow you to compare groups even if you have only one data point from each. But that requires additional assumptions and this comparison is still unlikely to tell you anything informative.

Comment: I plotted the data and extracted the values which are on between 95 percent confidence interval range. Are those values in the cases where there is a significant difference?

Comment: @shome As I said above: it is not meaningful to say there is a significant difference between any pair of points. That is a claim about the *population*.

Comment: then, how to claim about specific data points?

Comment: @shome You cannot, as I keep saying!